# This shell loop should work, no?

Tags: shell

I am learning shell programming (coming from Java and C++). I have this loop in a file called loop:

```
read count
i = 1
while [$i -le $count]
do
    echo This is loop $i of $count
    i='expr $i + 1'
done
```

It reads the input, but give the following errors:

```
./loop: line 2: i: command not found
./loop: line 3: [: missing `]'
```

I'm pretty sure that it's something silly. Thank you!

Comment: Unlike in Java and C++, you *cannot* have spaces around the `=` in assignments.

Comment: You need a space after the `[` and before the `]`.

Comment: And finally, `i='expr $i + 1'` should probably be `i=$(($i + 1))`.

Comment: Either that, or using backticks instead of simple quotes.

Comment: And I'm pretty sure this is bash or ksh. You should tag it with the appropriate shell.

Comment: I've seen this problem a number of times here; someone can mark it as a duplicate if they can track down a relevant question. The problem is that `[` isn't special shell syntax, it's a *command*, nearly equivalent to the `test` command. Like any command (built-in or not), it requires whitespace between the command name and the arguments, and between all arguments. The `]` is the last argument to the `[` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shells are pretty finicky about whitespace. Comments are inline.

```
read count
i=1                                 # spaces not allowed
while [ $i -le $count ]             # spaces required around brackets
do
    echo This is loop $i of $count
    i=$(expr $i + 1)                # need to use $(...) or `...` not '...'
done
```